# Evitar refresh al validar formulario

Tags: javascript, php, html

De momento valido mi formulario con php, una vez validado se inserta la información a la base de datos. El problema es que si un dato ingresado esta mal, me recarga la pagina. Intente hacer mi validación con java script y con `e.preventDefault()` resuelvo el problema del refresh, pero ahora nesecito ejecutar la consulta, alguna sugerencia? *--*

**Html**

```
<form id="tab9" class="form-reg-asesoria" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">

            <div class="label_alumno">
                <label for="">Nombre del alumno</label>
                <input class="input_alumno" type="text" id="nombre_alumno" name="nombre_alumno">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
                <label for="">No. Control del alumno</label>
                <input class="input_matricula" type="text" name="matricula" id="matricula">
            </div>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" class="consulta" name="Registrar_Docente" value="Registrar">
        </form>
```

**Php**

```
if(isset($_POST['Registrar_Docente'])){

 $matricula = $_POST['matricula'];
 $nombre = $_POST['nombre_alumno'];
 
 if(empty($matricula)){
    echo '<script> alert("Agrega tu matricula")</script>';
    exit;
}
if(empty($nombre)){
    echo '<script> alert("Agrega tu nombre")</script>';
 exit;
}else{

$objeto = new Conexion;
$conexion = $objeto->Conectar();

 $insertar = "INSERT INTO asesoria Values ($matricula', '$nombre')";

$resultado = $conexion->prepare($insertar);
$resultado->execute();

 $query = $resultado;
 if ($query){
     echo '<script> alert("Asesoria Guardada")</script>';
 }else{
    echo '<script> alert("Error al guardar")</script>';
 }
        }
    }
```

**JS**

```
const form = document.getElementById("tab9")
const nombre = document.getElementById("nombre_alumno")
const matricula = document.getElementById("matricula")

form.addEventListener("submit", e=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    if(nombre.value.length == 0){
        alert("El nombre es obligatorio")
    }
    if(matricula.value.length == 0){
        alert("La matricula es obligatoria")
    }
    if(tema.value.length == 0){
        alert("El tema es obligatorio")
    }
   
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Si tu validación tan solo es conseguir que el campo tenga contenido entonces puedes usar `require` como atributo en tus `input` y no te hace falta el javascript, el cual petará siempre cuando intenta calcular el `tema.value` porque `tema` no existe (al menos en el código de tu pregunta).

Por ejemplo así:

```
<input class="input_alumno" type="text" id="nombre_alumno" name="nombre_alumno" require>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando termines de hacer tu validacion, puedes hacer un form.submit() con el codigo que proporcionas podria ser algo como:

```
const form = document.getElementById("tab9")
const nombre = document.getElementById("nombre_alumno")
const matricula = document.getElementById("matricula")

form.addEventListener("submit", e=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    let submit =true;
    if(nombre.value.length == 0){
        submit=false;
        alert("El nombre es obligatorio")
    }
    if(matricula.value.length == 0){
        submit=false;
        alert("La matricula es obligatoria")
    }
    if (tema.value.length == 0) {
        submit = false;
        alert("El tema es obligatorio")
    }
    if(submit)
        form.submit();
})
```

Comment: Pero con ` form.submit();` que es lo que se ejecuta exactamente? mi input tipo submit? mi if de php?

Comment: form es tu variable de JavaScript donde tienes contenido tu formulario, el submit() lo unico que hace es ejecutarlo directamente.